# Scale down a border-radius div element and keep in same position, egg shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a div element in the shape of an egg and rotated 140 degrees.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="egg-container">
    <div id="egg-blue" class="egg egg-large"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#egg-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.egg {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#00F9AF, #0054FD 70%);
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset, 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 75px;
}

#egg-blue {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
    transform: rotate(140deg);
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.egg-lg {
    top: 25px;
    right: -25px;
    height: 160px;
    width: 140px;
}

.egg-md {
    /* How to scale down correctly? */
}

.egg-sm {
    /* How to scale down correctly? */
}

.egg-xs {
    /* How to scale down correctly? */
}
```

My goal is to leverage JavaScript to simply switch classes between large, medium, small and extra small. I know how to employ toggling classes.

But I'm having trouble connecting the dots on styling this correctly when classes change between `-lg`, `-md`, `-sm`, `-xs`. It looks too snappy, choppy, etc.

Another way to imagine this outside of code is a flower blooming. When I toggle the class with JavaScript, that's essentially what I am trying to accomplish. Do note, the red circle styling is there to act as a visual center.

I want that egg that you see illustrated to maintain its **aspect ratio** AND its **rotation**. Simply scale the element bigger or smaller, depending on the applied class selector.

I figure the root of my problem at the moment is that I am hard-coding pixel widths and heights.

If you have any ideas, please chime in.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/excqrun0/12/

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by flip classes? Do you mean to flip the egg shape?

Comment: I'll reword the inquiry but essentially, change the egg shape size, yes - based on toggling classes. But I want the position of that egg shape to stay there. Just scale the size up or down. Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `transform : scale(0.5);` to scale down the element : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

and you can add it to your previous `transform` like `transform: rotate(140deg) scale(1);` , move the width and height and other stuff to the `id` `egg-blue` and fill the classes with the new `transform` , and use javascript to switch between the classes :

```js
var egg = document.getElementById('egg-blue');  
    
document.getElementById('big').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    egg.classList.add("egg-large");
    egg.classList.remove("egg-medium");
    egg.classList.remove("egg-small");
});

document.getElementById('medium').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    egg.classList.add("egg-medium");
    egg.classList.remove("egg-large");
    egg.classList.remove("egg-small");
});

document.getElementById('small').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    egg.classList.add("egg-small");
    egg.classList.remove("egg-large");
    egg.classList.remove("egg-medium");
});
```

```css
#egg-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.egg {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#00F9AF, #0054FD 70%);
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset, 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 75px;
}
                
#egg-blue {
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 25px;
  right: -25px;
  height: 160px;
  width: 140px;
}

.egg-large {
  transform: rotate(140deg) scale(1);
}

.egg-medium {
  transform: rotate(140deg) scale(0.7);
}

.egg-small {
  transform: rotate(140deg) scale(0.4);
}

#buttons{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="egg-container">
    <div id="egg-blue" class="egg egg-large"></div>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
    <button id="big"> BIG </button>
    <button id="medium"> MEDium </button>
    <button id="small"> small </button>    
 </div>
```